# Prometheus staleness

Tags: prometheus

Reading Prometheus documentation about [staleness](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/basics/#staleness), I understood :

- A time serie which no longer exist for a target is marked as staled
- Times series of a removed target are marked as staled
- If the latest sample from a time serie is older than 5 minutes then no sample is returned

I don't understand the last sentence :

> Staleness will not be marked for time series that have timestamps included in their scrapes. Only the 5 minute threshold will be applied in that case.

What does `"time series that have timestamps included in their scrapes"` actually mean ?

It would be easier to understand with a concrete example.

Answer (score 2):

Metrics can be exposed with explicitly stated timestamp.

Format described [here](https://prometheus.io/docs/instrumenting/exposition_formats/#comments-help-text-and-type-information) is used for it:

> ```
> metric_name [
>  "{" label_name "=" `"` label_value `"` { "," label_name "=" `"` label_value >`"` } [ "," ] "}"
> ] value [ timestamp ]
> ```

If Prometheus scrapes metrics with specified timestamp - only the rule of timeout (default 5 minutes) is applied.

Metrics with timestamp are not required to be present on every scrape. Not to be marked as stale it is enough for them to be re-scraped at least once in the 5 minutes window from last timestamp.

On the other hand, "usual" metric if missing from scrape set of target will be automatically marked as stale.

Comment: I didn't know we could expose metrics with timestamp. The sentence is obvious once we know it. But I don't really see the use case, I never saw an application that doesn't expose all its metrics. What is the benefit of exposing a metric only at specific instant. Maybe to reduce the metrics service response size ?

Comment: @OlivierBoissé, for "usual" metrics - if you have some subroutine, you can expose it's metric only when it is active, for example. For "timestamped" - if metrics is costly to recalc, you can significantly lower impact exposing it only once every 5 minute, as opose to default 15 seconds.